# Not Understanding Void Pointer / How to cast? (C Programming)

Tags: c, arrays, casting, void-pointers

Suppose I want to write a function: 
`int read_file (char *filename, void *abc)`
that reads the file, and puts the numbers in an array, which `abc` points to. 
I must use the void pointer - I know how I would do it if it were `int *abc` instead of void, as I could treat `abc` syntactically like an array, and do stuff like `abc[0]=1`, but here I can't do that, as it's a void pointer.

I'm not too familiar with void pointers, and how I should get this to work. Please help! I prefer not to post code, as this is for a school assignment, and just want to know how I would put the information in the file into an array pointed to by `abc`, maybe with casting (not sure how to do that though).

I am already familiar with putting file information into an array, if it's given by `int abc`.

Comment: Not clear what you ask. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf - What's not clear? The guy has a function which gets passed a `void *` parameter (which he knows contains a pointer to an `int` array), and he wonders how he can get to the `int` array to work with it. It's homework, he's obviously learning the fundamentals of C.

Comment: Why must you use ` void *` in the function argument list?  Do you know that it is always an array of `int` that is being pointed to?  If you do have to use a `void *` in the function argument list, but you know it is always an `int *` behind the scenes, you can use `int read_file(char *filename, void *vp_abc) { int *abc = vp_abc; …rest of code as before… }` — simply coerce the pointless void pointer into the type you really want.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. I tried some type-casting which I saw, and it didn't work. I will try to fix my program with that.

Comment: OK, so suppose I do what you wrote ^ (and it compiles), but now I want to do `int main () { int stuff[1000]; read_file("file.txt", stuff); return 0;}` in order to get the file data into `stuff`, it gives me an error. What am I missing?

Comment: Never mind - my array i used was too small! When I used a larger array, the program ran smoothly, and I got the desired printf results... thank you...

Comment: @Vilx-: How do you know it is an `int *`? There is only some "if it was ..." statement. If that is, he should use `int *`, not `void *` - never use `void *` without true need.

Comment: The school assignment required the void pointer in this case, just to clarify. And yes, that's a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `read_file` is always called with an `int` array for the `abc` parameter, you can just copy it to an `int` pointer and work with that.

```
int *p = abc;
```

In most cases, you need to cast when changing from one type to another, however a `void *` may be freely cast to or from any non-function pointer without a cast safely.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath the hood all pointers are the same - they're integers which represent memory addresses. So you can cast them every which way. Just go:

```
int *p = (int *)abc;
```

And voila - you have your `int *` which you already know how to deal with. This is the "casting" thing, by the way - write the desired type in parentheses in front of your expression to "cast" it. It'll take the same bits and reinterpret them in a different way.

In a few cases C is actually smart enough to convert the data rather than blindly use the same bits. For example:

```
float f = 3.75;
int i = (int)f;
```

In this case `i` will contain `3` because it rounds down in this case. And an `int` is stored in memory differently than a `float`, so there is actual conversion going on here.

And in other cases it will forbid you to cast at all, because of how little sense it makes:

```
char *c = "Hello, world!";
float f = (float)c;
```

But quite often you can get away with it. Especially with pointers, everything is fair game. Now, mind you, with great power comes great responsibility. Although you *can* do it, doesn't mean that the result will be sensible and that using it won't crash your program. Be careful.